# How to force a particular version of Java?

Tags: linux, rhel, path, java

I am on a RHEL 5.5 64 bit box.  The systems engineer installed the 64-bit Java VM under `/usr/bin` ; however, I needed a 32 bit VM which he installed in `/opt/jdk1.6.0_35`. But now, everytime I do `java -version` it shows that I'm using the 64-bit VM.

How do I force it to select the 32 bit VM? I changed the PATH to not include `/usr/bin`, but that's where most of the important programs like vi and nano are, and I cannot exclude that.

Is there another variable I can add to force it to select the 32 bit VM by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to put the location of the new binary in your `PATH` first. When you try to run java, the shell will search your path for the first instance and run it. Try this:

```
$ export PATH=/opt/jdk1.6.0_35/bin:$PATH
```

That's assuming you're using bash, or a similar shell. Now any commands that exist in /usr/bin/ will be overridden by those in the new directory.